# Why does dpkg not work with no error code?

Tags: dpkg

```
$ sudo dpkg --unpack ubuntu-cli
(Reading database ... 57147 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ubuntu-cli ...
Unpacking minergate (7.1-gcc4) over (7.1-gcc4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
```

But it does not get unpacked.

Comment: What do you expect `--unpack` to do? Are you looking for `--extract` instead?

Comment: I'm assuming it works something like unzipping. The tutorial I was following actually used -i

Comment: `-i` is for installation, `-x` or `--extract` is for unzipping and `--unpack` is for unpacking the package (over existing package, if another version is already installed) without configuring in root directory (or wherever the package is to be installed). If `-x`/`--extract` achieve what you are looking for, I'll post an answer.